# Collision for a Static Wall

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I have to program a game for college and I am trying to get a static wall to be an obstacle for the player so the player cannot move through it.

```
            if (rectangle1.Right == (wallRect.Left) && rectangle1.Bottom >= wallRect.Top && rectangle1.Top <= wallRect.Bottom)
        {
            rightMovement = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rightMovement = true;
        }
```

Below is the code for the control input.

```
        if (rightMovement == true)
        {
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || currentGamePadState.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                player1.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
            }
        }
```

Currently, if I start from the left of the screen and move into the wall the collision works fine, then when I move to the other side of the wall the collision doesn't work then when I move to the right hand side edge of the screen and move into the wall collision works on the right side of the wall but then I can move through the left hand side of the wall. I have written code for the collision on the left and right side of the wall.

Comment: You should represent your wall and player bounds using `Rectangle`, if they do `Intersects()` then act accordingly. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx. Extra tip : when your player will move more pixels per frame than your wall's width, it will pass through it : you might want to look to continuous collision detection then.

Answer (score 0):

1) define 8 vertices, 4 at the coordinates of the player's bounding rectangle original location and 4 for it's new location.
2) define all posible triangles made of these vertices.
3) if one of the triangles intersects with one of the wall's edges than they have collided in this frame.
4) by getting the intersection's min and max positions you can know the collision's coordinates.